# Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable with PHP 7.4?

Tags: count, php-7.4

I am getting "Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable" for this line of code:

```
$parent = $path[count($path)-1];
```

How would I rewrite it so it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `$path` variable  is not an array type data structure or other iterable structure.
Without context, it is impossible to understand how you should rewrite this code.
You shouldn't run this piece of code without checking that the `$path` variable is not an array. This can be done by calling the `is_array()` function.
I also noticed that you are trying to get the last element of the array via `count($path)-1`. It is better to do this through the `end()` function, but you should pay attention to the fact that this function shifts the array pointer.